# STM32L0 Pulse Counting in Stop mode

Tags: stm32, pulse

I am reading that the STM32L0 supports async pulse counting in sleep mode. However, I can't
find any documentation on how to actually do this. I am wondering if anyone here has attempted this
or knows anything about it? Here is the doc that seems to say it is supported: [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an4865-lowpower-timer-lptim-applicative-use-cases-on-stm32-mcus-and-mpus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)
My goal is to count 3.3v pulses that I get from an outside source, I am really hoping I can save my device's battery as much as possible. If I can just tap into the other devices gnd, and then wire the 3.3v pulse into the STM32L0, I think that should be good for reading the signal, but I need to figure out how to configure the async counter.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried reading through the low power timer section of the reference manual of the MCU?

Comment: You have some pretty good search terms such as "autonomous mode". What have you found so far?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes, Specifically section 3.15.2 of the datasheet: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l051r8.pdf
and I did find a github repo: https://github.com/cnoviello/mastering-stm32/blob/master/nucleo-l073RZ/system/src/stm32l0xx/stm32l0xx_hal_lptim.c#L32
I was however hoping there is some sort of example I could work from. All attempts I have made so far have not worked :(

Comment: There is an interesting Tutorial here on counting: https://deepbluembedded.com/stm32-counter-mode-example-frequency-counter-timer-in-counter-mode/
However, nothing about doing it in sleep mode, whenever I attempt sleep mode, when waking, I don't have the counts.

Comment: read about LPTIM peripheral